# Who wins in this simple "factoring game" depending on the starting number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, game-theory, prime-factorization, combinatorial-game-theory

There is a given $N$ written on a board. Two players, Alice and Bob choose a number from the board and factorize that number to $N=XY$ where $\gcd(X,Y)\neq1$, then erase $N$ and write $X, Y$ on the board. If anyone can't factorize any number on the board, they lose. I think someone has a winning strategy in this game depending on the starting number $N$. (Zermelo's Theorem) For which $N$ does Alice have a winning strategy?

Here's what I've got.
For $N=p^{2k+1}$, Bob wins.

For a $N=k^2$ for some integer $k$, Alice wins. (Factorize $N=k\cdot{k}$ then mirror Bob's factorization.)

For other $N$, who wins? Is there an deterministic algorithm to check who wins? Or is there a closed form of $N$ that Alice wins?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This only depends on the number of prime factors of $N$, right? If the number of prime factors is even then Alice wins and if it is odd then Bob wins.

Comment: @Marcos Let's think about $N=2^43^35^4$, then if I factorize $X=2^3*5^2$ and $Y=2*3^3*5^2$ then Alice can use the same mirroring strategy because the set of exponents of $X, Y$ is same. Note that if the exponent of some prime divisor is $1$, we can just ignore that divisor. This is where I got stuck.

Comment: This is just Nim. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim

Comment: @CyclotomicField Is it Nim even though the number of piles increase, and there is a gcd condition?

Comment: Nim has many variations, like [Grundy's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game) which this is somewhat similar to. It can be analysed the same way due to the [Sprague Grundy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem). You just have to find the nim-values for small N, until hopefully a pattern appears so that you can work out a general strategy and classify which N are a win for Alice or Bob.

Comment: @Hypernova the primes are the piles, their multiplicity is the size of the pile.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Are you saying that say, $N=2^{3}$ is equivalent to a single nim heap with size $3$? This is not correct; a single nim heap is a winning position, while $N=2^{3}$ is a losing position in this game.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I tried the analysis by finding the Nim values, but I couldn't find a meaningful result. I'm struggling to generalize it.. Can it be random??